# TypeError: an integer is required When using PhraseMatcher with fuzzy matching in Spcay

Tags: nlp, spacy, spacy-3

Code that i tried using.
Instead of `["awesome", "cool", "wonderful"]` list I just have a longer list of 100s of element.

```
from spacy.matcher import PhraseMatcher
nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_trf")
matcher = PhraseMatcher(nlp.vocab, attr="LOWER")  # attr="LOWER"

pattern = [{"TEXT": {"FUZZY": {"IN": ["awesome", "cool", "wonderful"]}}}]

# matcher.add("match1", *patterns)
matcher.add("match2", patterns)
```

I am using the spacy version 3.5.2

Error Traceback:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[103], line 7
      3 matcher = PhraseMatcher(nlp.vocab, attr="LOWER")  # attr="LOWER"
      5 pattern = [{"TEXT": {"FUZZY": {"IN": ["awesome", "cool", "wonderful"]}}}]
----> 7 matcher.add("match1", *patterns)
      8 # matcher.add("match2", patterns)

File c:\Users\InfraBlok\Documents\repository\Discovery\.venv\lib\site-packages\spacy\matcher\phrasematcher.pyx:221, in spacy.matcher.phrasematcher.PhraseMatcher.add()

TypeError: an integer is required
```

I expects that the above code to match the fuzzy text strings providing in the list.
Following the this doc form [spacy](https://spacy.io/usage/rule-based-matching#regex-fuzzy-lists)